# Why this second div is shown under the first div that precedes it?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, themes

I have the following situation (I can't post an online fiddle because it is the rendered result of a JSP that use Struts 2 tag). In a page I have something like this:

```
<td id="rightColumn" width="66.6%">
    <div id="resultEvents" class="class java.util.HashMap">
        <table class="contacts" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>.....</tr>
                <tr>.....</tr>
                <tr>.....</tr>
                <tr>.....</tr>
                <tr>.....</tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>

         <br>

    </div>

    <div id="wwctrl_submitButton" align="right" style="display: block">
        <input id="submitButton" type="submit" style="" onclick="return validateForm();" value="Submit" name="action:projectCreationAction">
    </div>
</td>
```

And this is the obtained result:

[image]

As you can see the problem is that the **submit button** represented by the content of this div:

```
<div id="wwctrl_submitButton" align="right" style="display: block">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" style="" onclick="return validateForm();" value="Submit" name="action:projectCreationAction">
</div>
```

appear under its previous div (the div having **id=resultEvents**)

This is the CSS related to the previous HTML code snippet:

```
#treeFormContainer {
    min-height: 250px;
}

#rightColumn {
    position: relative;
}

#resultEvents {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

How to prevent this behavior and show the div having **id="wwctrl_submitButton"** UNDER the previous div having **id="resultEvents"**?

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: I don't see in your code any reference to **z-index**?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order

Comment: By the way, there are problems with your code. For instance, the `width` attribute, when used with a fractional percentage, is incompatible among browsers. Use a `style`. And this is supposed to be XHTML, right? Then use `<br />`, not `<br>`.

Answer (score 0):

It hard without a fiddle to play around with. 
However I can see a closed td tag after your table and div closes. Try removing this as it may be effecting the layout.

Comment: The OP's code also contains the start tag for the td you mention, at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why the `wwctrl_submitButton` div doesn't start until after the end of the table, that is because the `resultEvents` div is positioned absolutely, so the `wwctrl_submitButton` div is drawn in the location where it would be drawn if the first div hadn't been present at all.

Solution: place the div in a location below the table manually, for instance with `position:absolute` and a `top` value at least as great as the height of the table.
Alternatively, if you can change the HTML, put the second div directly behind the table, inside the first div.

Or if your question is why the table is drawn on top of the `wwctrl_submitButton` div, elements with `position:absolute` are drawn on top of elements with no positioning.

So then the solution would be to give `wwctrl_submitButton` a `position` too, for instance `position:relative`, without doing anything else.

Answer (score -2):

add this css replace absolute position:

```
 #resultEvents {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @MohammedHâmzã
It's not true. position:relative -  'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties apply. More info at W3C: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position

Comment: I can see a closed td tag after the table is closed.